# add nsstring to local html file in main bundle ios

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview, nsstring

Hey guys at the moment i am not at home so i cannot really provide any code so i will try to explain my problem.
In my ios application i am trying to implement an image gallery using [photoswipe](http://www.photoswipe.com), that depending on which restaurant is chosen in the uitableview, will show different images.
To test this, i have imported all the necessary html, javascript, css files in my main bundle, then i loaded the index.html file in my uiwebview. At the moment the gallery is showing the same images for every restaurant chosen because the index.html file is holding static url links to some test images, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>PhotoSwipe</title>
<meta name="author" content="Ste Brennan - Code Computerlove -http://www.codecomputerlove.com/" />
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0;" name="viewport" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<link href="styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="../photoswipe.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/klass.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../code.photoswipe-3.0.5.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

    (function(window, PhotoSwipe){

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

            var
                options = {},
                instance = PhotoSwipe.attach( window.document.querySelectorAll('#Gallery a'), options );

        }, false);


    }(window, window.Code.PhotoSwipe));

</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="MainContent">

<ul id="Gallery" class="gallery">
    <!-- ---------------------------LOOK HERE------------ -->

    <li><a href="TEST IMAGE 1 URL"><img src="THUMBNAIL TEST IMAGE 1 URL" alt="Image 001" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="TEST IMAGE 2 URL"><img src="THUMBNAIL TEST IMAGE 2 URL" alt="Image 002" /></a></li>
</ul>

</div>  


</body>
</html>
```

Is there anyway of injecting an nsstring to this local html file containing links to the relative restaurant chosen?

I've tried using `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` to overwrite the html content of the `<ul>` with id "Gallery", but this slows done the process of outputting the images to the thumbnail grid.

Is there a way of editing the local index.html file on the fly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the NSString method,  `stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:` to get the whole content of html file, edit it and then set it back using `writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:`. Or maybe use the NSFileHandle methods for more low level access.

**EDIT:**

To get the documents directory:

```
NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
```

Then append your file name to it.

```
NSString *htmlFilePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"index.html"];
```

and use the above path as a parameter to `writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:`

Comment: Thanks @Rakesh for answering so quickly, i really apreciate it. Tomorrow when i get back home i will try your solution straight away. Thanks again

Comment: Sorry for answering so late. Anyway i tried using the 2 methods you suggested me. I get no errors, but the html file is not updating, i thinks its due to the fact that it is an illegal operaton to edit the main bundle during run time [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW2) .Could i copy all the html,css,javascript files in the documents directory, modify the index.html file, then load the updated index.html file to the uiwebview?

Comment: yes i guess so. as long as the file is not in main bundle it wont be a problem to edit it. Use the updated html in the documents folder to load your web view instead of the html file in the main bundle . That should solve the problem.

Comment: i tried to but i can't because i haven't got 15 reputation points yet :(

Answer (score 1):

I needed to display previously saved HTML from my apps rich text editor.  I tried several javascript injection solutions but the following NSString replacement solution was the smoothest.

In my detail viewDidLoad I use a template html file and when the user selects the document from a master uitableview I do a simple replacement operation to put in some previously saved text:

```
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"iosDemo1" ofType:@"html"];
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSString *html = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

    NSLog(@" html %@",html);
    // Replace text "Marker" in the template with the previously saved rich text editor html 
    NSString* modifiedHtml = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Marker" withString:self.htmlDocumentText];

    // Tell the web view to load the modified Html
    [self.webView loadHTMLString:modifiedHtml baseURL:nil];
```